# How to fetch one by one inside oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement a oracle procedure which includes some processors inside.

So I need to know how to get selected items to a particular array and fetch it into particulate type and do the process. I hope below code may helpful.

inside the procedure:

```
array_ := select name from employee; /*varchar2*/

/*get one by one*/

for employee in array loop
text = employee; /*now this is in varchar2*/ 
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a cursor explicitly:

```
declare 
    cursor employees is 
     select name from employee;

    var_name employees.name%type;

begin

    for employee in employees loop

      var_name := employee.name;
      --your processing here          

    end loop;

end;
```